# Problema com cookie no PHP

Tags: php, cookies, condição

Estou desenvolvendo um sistema em PHP para bares e restaurantes, que ao entrar na página inicial um cookie é settado com o número da mesa, após o cookie ser settado, tem uma condicional abaixo verificando se realmente o cookie foi settado para continuar a operação, porém ele nunca entra de primeira na condição, quando o cookie é settado, preciso dar um refresh na página para ele entrar na condição e só assim continuar a operação. Gostaria de saber porque ele não entra na condição de primeira sem dar refresh. (obs: já tentei usar tanto a função isset quanto empty e não funcionou).

[image: Esta é a minha condicional que só é verdadeira após dar o refresh na página.]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá, de acordo com a [documentação oficial](https://www.php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.setcookie.php):

- Uma vez que os cookies foram setados, eles podem ser acessados no próximo carregamento da página através do array $_COOKIE.

Ou seja, o que você tá tentando fazer não vai funcionar mesmo, pois o cookie só é setado quando os cabeçalhos HTTP são enviados.

Para resolver o seu problema, você pode usar uma flag quando verificar se o cookie existe.

```
$valorCookie = 'seu-valor';
if(!isset($_COOKIE[$_cookieSession])) {
   setcookie($_cookieSession, $valorCookie);
   $firstAccess = true;
}

if($firstAccess) {
   $crypt0 = $valorCookie;
} else {
   $crypt0 = $_COOKIE[$_cookieSession];
}

list($origem, $horai, $mesar0) = explode('#', $crypt0);
```

Comment: valeu dms irmão

Comment: Nada, não esquece de marcar a resposta como certa para ajudar os próximos